# Is this way of reversing a string safe?

Tags: c++, string

I am wondering is this way of reversing a string is safe?

```
void ReverseString( std::string & stringToReverse )
{
    stringToReverse.assign( stringToReverse.rbegin(), stringToReverse.rend() );
}
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with using `std::reverse()`?

Comment: It just did not occur to me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to §21.4.6.3/20, `assign(first,last)` (with iterators `first` and `last`) is equivalent to

```
assign(string(first,last))
```

Hence it first creates a new string object and then assigns it. There is no risk that the string you copy from (in reverse) is being modified while you still copy (if that is what you were afraid of).

However, using `std::reverse(begin(str),end(str))` as suggested by the others is better and potentially more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a request to have your code reviewed, or you don't know about other options, but you should just use `std::reverse` from `<algorithm>`

```
std::string str = "Hello world!";
std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
```

This reverses the string in place. If you wanted to create a new string, you're essentially doing what you have in you code using `assign()` but with the `std::string` constructor:

```
std::string reversed(str.rbegin(), str.rend());
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by others, what you did, in fact, reverses the `char` sequence.
The fact this actually reverses the *string* depends on what the concept of "*reverse*" and "*string*" and "*char*" are meant to be.

An `std::string` is a sequence of `char` that are 8 bit long (at least on the most platforms).
A Japanese string (but even a French or Italian or German one) can contain codepoints that are outside the 0..127 range, and hence need to be encode somewhat to be represented into 8 bit characters, so a "character" may keep more than 1 `char`. An putting the `char`-s in reverse order doesn't reverse the text, it just mess it out completely.

Assuming `1 character <=> 1 char` is true only for pure ASCII text.